# Custom PL/SQL functions for dual-column primary key to put in form creator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a table with primary key that consist of two columns and both are foreign keys. I'm creating form on this table and wizard require either sequence or trigger or custom PL/SQL function. I want to get values for both columns from items that will be located on form and filled when redirecting from another page to this page (that I'm creating).

Does function is good solution in this case? How this function should look? Could you write me an example, please? Sample hidden item to be used in form would be P21_ID_ROW_FK.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, I suggest you create a surrogate primary key on your table, and populate it using a sequence or a trigger. Create a unique constraint on your two foreign key columns.

I don't want to start a surrogate vs natural key debate here. Some frameworks, including Apex, just seem to be designed with surrogate keys in mind, the current question being a case in point.